# Resets the stacks view when the root controller is a tab bar controller

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, reset

I have a tab bar controller and in both tab bar items i have a nav controller in each. I would like that whenever a user goes away and back to a tab bar item it resets the nav controller.

If I've been navigating in one of the tab bar and then i press another tab item and go back it takes me to the beginning of the navigation.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what it works for me...

I made the appDelegate a UITableBarViewControllerDelegate too.

```
@interface InterfacesAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate> {
```

After, In IB I connected the tabbarcontrollerDelegate to the appDelegate. In this case Interfaces App Delegate

As Ben said, I then implemented the abBarController:shouldSelectViewController under InterfacesAppDelegate.m

Answer (score 3):

Set yourself to be the delegate of the tabBarController, and whenever you get a -tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController: message, call -popToRootViewController on your tab's navigation controller.

Comment: ok i got almost all but how to set myself as the delegate.. The project has appDelegate. How do you set the delegate and where should i do it??

I was trying to do it in the viewDidUnload of the nav controller

Comment: You need to really understand delegates to make much headway in Objective C. Take a look at the documentation for the UITabBarController, but basically: controller.delegate = self.

Comment: I'll post my answer, what worked for me... I try reading apple's documentation for delegates but i didn't understand much beyond the general meaning. That is, that delegates it's a part of the code that you can call from everywhere and it does an action returning something to the caller.